# Unwanted request to pypi.org while using local PyPI server

Tags: python, pip, gitlab, pypi

My need is to make the truly autonomous PyPi server.

Our admins established our own PyPi server, hosted on Gitlab, and I uploaded there all packages I need.
Everything works fine, the packages are downloaded from my server, while there is a connection to pypi.org.

The command:

```
pip install --index-url <my_gitlab_package_index> my_package
```

But when I prevent the connection to pypi.org, I got the message:

```
Could not fetch URL https://for_download:****@gitlab.local/local/api/v4/projects/.../packages/pypi/simple/my_package: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/my_package/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))) - skipping
```

Please, don't consider the certificate problem, the preventing way could be different. pip must not connect to the global pypi.org at all.

What can you advice?

Update: the log with -vv:

The log became different, but the result is the same. What does it mean, something about "verbose"? It tries to connect to pypi.org. The log:

```
Looking in indexes: https://for_download:****@mycompvgit.mycomp.local/api/v4/projects/advanced_algorithms%2fadvanced_technologies/packages/pypi/simple
1 location(s) to search for versions of ditryjson:
...
https://for_download:****@mycompvgit.mycomp.local/api/v4/projects/advanced_algorithms%2fadvanced_technologies/packages/pypi/simple/ditryjson/
Getting page https://for_download:****@mycompvgit.mycomp.local/api/v4/projects/advanced_algorithms%2fadvanced_technologies/packages/pypi/simple/ditryjson/
Found credentials in url for mycompvgit.mycomp.local
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): mycompvgit.mycomp.local:443
https://mycompvgit.mycomp.local:443 "GET /api/v4/projects/advanced_algorithms%2Fadvanced_technologiesn/packages/pypi/simple/ditryjson/ HTTP/1.1" 302 81
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
```

Comment: Run `pip` with `-vv` and see what it tries to do!

Comment: The log is too long to paste in comment, so I updated the question.

Comment: Your server returns a 302 pointing to pypi.org. Looks like there is something missing on the server.

Comment: You totally right. I pasted the api url to the browser and got the redirect. Thank you.

Comment: The second attempt - and it shows my package in the broswer. pip is still redirected.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that pip my local Gitgub pypi server redirected the pip client request because pip client tries to check it's version.
The '--disable-pip-version-check' resolved the problem.